# Conflict between PCL and ROS Kinect drivers..Any Soln?

Tags: ros, kinect, pcl, libopenni, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 12.04 and Fuerte with rosbuild

I have a kinect for xbox 360. I installed a fresh copy of ubuntu 12.04, fuerte and added a patch from

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/attachment/ticket/5243/perception_pcl-1.0.1-vtk5.8.patch

and got openni_launch to work. I was able to visualize point clouds from kinect in rviz.

Then I installed PCL binaries for ubuntu and it has removed some openni drivers for ROS.

After this the openni_launch package does not work, no pointclouds.

When I try to install the removed packages, like "libopenni-dev" or "libopenni0", it says there is conflict with PCL libraries asks if they can be removed.

How to solve this issue?

How can I get kinect working with ROS and have PCL libraries for features, keypoints and registration purposes?
Specifically no need of the PCL driver for kinect as I will subscribe to pointclouds from ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64884/conflict-between-pcl-and-ros-kinect-drivers..any-soln?/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is [here](http://www.pcl-users.org/Conflict-between-PCL-and-ROS-Kinect-drivers-Any-Soln-td4028212.html).
Basically PCL and ROS have incompatible versions of Kinect drivers. You can have one or the other installed but not both. If you want to use PCL with ROS you have to use the ROS version of PCL which is very limited compared to trunk PCL as far as I understand (I have not tested it myself).

---

Originally posted by [aecins](https://answers.ros.org/users/1744/aecins/) with karma: 113 on 2013-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1